# I don't want ajax submit / callback validate form '#required' => TRUE,

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I have form with static fields and dynamic fields as follow:

fieldset

1. textfield00 (require = true)
2. textfield01 (require = true)

fieldset

3. textfield02

fieldset

4. add textfield
5. submit button

so, everytime add textfield pressed, it will add new/duplicate textfield02.

with add textfield code as follow:

```
$form['fields']['modules']['add'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#name' => 'addtextfield',
      '#value' => t('Add more TextField'),
      '#submit' => array(array($this, 'addTextfieldSubmit')),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => array($this, 'addTextFieldCallback'),
        'wrapper' => 'wrapper',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
    );
```

the adding field is working fine, the only problem i have here is: because textfield00 and textfield01 is mandatory, if i pressed add button, it will send me an error message 'mandatory fields' before i can add new textfield.

so how can i 'bypass' the requried validation, everytime i press add textfiled and only validate 'required = true' when i press submit button.

Thank You,
AnD

Comment: Add the #limit_validation_errors property to your ajax button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'#limit_validation_errors' => array();**

```
$form['actions']['previous'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Previous'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(
      // Validate $form_state->getValue('step1').
      array('step1'),
      // Validate $form_state->getValue(array('foo', 'bar')).
      array('foo', 'bar'),
    ),
    '#submit' => array('some_submit_function'), // #submit required.
  );
```